# How can I format a float to variable precision?

Tags: python

I would like to have a function that formats a float to a variable length of precision. For example, if I pass in n=2, I would expect a precision of 1.67; if I pass in `n=5`, I would expect `1.66667`.

I currently have the following, but I feel like there would be an easier way to do so. Is there?

```
def my_precision(x, n):
    fmt = '{:.%df}' % n
    return fmt.format(x)
```

Comment: To me, it looks like you already answered your own question. Does what you wrote there not work?

Comment: `return '{:.{prec}f}'.format(x, prec=n)` is slightly neater, but not by much! It seems very odd to mix `%` formatting with `str.format` - note that you can use e.g. `'{{:.{}f}}'.format(n)` to escape the braces.

Comment: @DanGetz my solution works, but i was worrisome about mixing both string formatting.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your solution is fine.

However, as a personal matter of style, I tend to use either only `%`, or only `str.format()`.

So in this case I would define your formatting function as:

```
def my_precision(x, n):
    return '{:.{}f}'.format(x, n)
```

(thanks to @MarkDickinson for suggesting an shorter alternative to `'{{:.{:d}f}}'.format(n).format(x)`)

---

Incidentally, you can simply do:

```
my_precision = '{:.{}f}'.format
```

and it works:

```
>>> my_precision(3.14159, 2)
'3.14'
```

:-)

Comment: @mescalinum thanks, i didn't like mixing the formatting either and was not sure how the formatting would have worked properly with just using `str.format()`.

Answer (score 21):

### In 2019 with Python >= 3.6

From Python 3.6 with PEP 498, you can use "f-strings" to format like this

```
>>> x = 123456
>>> n = 3
>>> f"{x:.{n}f}"
'123456.000'
```

Reference here for more detail:

- [PEP 498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)
- [realpython.com Guide](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/)

Answer (score -1):

you can use thisdirectly :

```
my_precision = lambda x, n: '{}'.format(round(x, n))
```

Comment: Note that `round` returns a `float`, so can still be affected by precision issues.