# Correct typing with typescript on "nameless" key

Tags: json, typescript, vue.js

Im not there grasping Typescript and have the down below situation.

**Goal:**
Output quiz on single page based on quizId which is the starting number in below JSON.

**Expected and actual result:** 
Expected result is to be able to fetch single quiz based on the quizId from a JSON-file containing all the quizes with question and answer.

Actual result throws a type error from my code.

**Error message:**
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type

**Tried following:**
Below is the interface:

```
export interface Question {
  id: number;
  answer: string;
  correct: boolean;
}

export interface Questions {
  questionId: number;
  question: string;
  answers: [Question];
}

export interface Quiz {
  url: string;
  name: string;
  description: string;
  questions: [Questions];
}
```

My code:

```
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue, Prop } from 'vue-property-decorator';
import { QuizIndex } from '@/models/quiz.interface';
import MultiQuizQuestion from '@/components/multi-quiz-question.json';
@Component({})
export default class QuizPage extends Vue {
  @Prop() public quizIndex!: QuizIndex;
  // quizId!: number;
  private multiQuizQuestions = MultiQuizQuestion;
  private quizUrl: string = '';
  private quizId!: number;

  private created() {
    this.quizUrl = this.$route.params.id;
  }

  private get currentQuiz() {
    this.quizId = Object.values(this.multiQuizQuestions).findIndex(object => object.url == this.quizUrl);
    console.log(this.multiQuizQuestions[this.quizId]); // <-- This brings me the error

    return '';
  }
};
</script>
```

I have a JSON-file where I have quizes with quesiton and answers. Which have the following structure.

```
{
"1": {
    "url": "car-quiz",
    "name": "Car Quiz",
    "description": "This is a quiz about cars",
    "questions": [
        {
            "questionId": 1,
            "question": "What car is the best",
            "answers": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "answer": "Toyota,
                "correct": false
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "answer": "Ferrari",
                "correct": true
            }
            ]
        },
        {
            "questionId": 2,
            "question": "What car does James Bond like",
            "answers": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "answer": "Nissan",
                "correct": false
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "answer": "Aston Martin",
                "correct": true
            },
            ]
        },
    ]
},
"2": {
    "url": "hockey-quiz",
    "name": "Hockey Quiz",
    "questions": [
        {
            "questionId": 1,
            "question": "What does NHL stand for?",
            "answers": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "answer": "National Hockey Leauge",
                "correct": true
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "answer": "National Horse Leauge",
                "correct": false
            },
            ]
        },
    ]
}
```

}

**Summary:**
Im not sure how to use the interface here with a key "that doesnt have a name" from the JSON and then refer it to the Quiz, like following:

```
export interface QuizIndex {
  quizId: [Quiz];
}
```

I understand that the quizId in `this.multiQuizQuestions[this.quizId]` is not typed right, but Im not able to figure out how its supposed to be done. I want to learn this and not take the shortcut to turn on `"noImplicitAny": false`

Comment: FYI `[Thing]` isn't an array of Things; it's a [tuple type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30897226/how-can-i-format-a-float-to-variable-precision), an array containing exactly one single Thing. Also you don't seem to be describing the type of the data imported from the JSON file anywhere.

Comment: `[Thing]` is a valid TypeScript annotation for the more common `Thing[]` array.

Comment: @Martin sorry, the link above was wrong; no, it's a [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple), **not** an [array](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#array).

Comment: This was standard array annotation from about version 0.1 up to at least 2.4.1 https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=2.4.1#code/G4QwTgBAZgXBDaBnALmAlgOwOYF0IF4EByKAe1KIBoIiAjcInAbiA

Answer (score 0):

It is not an array of Quiz, it is an indexed object of Quiz. Use a Record utility type

```
export type QuizIndex = Record<string, Quiz>;
```

Or with an index signature

```
export interface QuizIndex {
  [quizId: string]: Quiz;
}
```